# Swift AnyObject Parameters

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the following initializer in my Swift application:

```
init(items :NSArray, identifier :String, configureCellClosure: (cell :AnyObject, item :AnyObject) -> ()) {

}
```

Now, I need to utilize so I do the following:

```
 let sessionsDataSource = SessionsDataSource(items: [], identifier: "") { (cell :UITableViewCell, item :Session) -> () in


        }
```

But it complains about me specifying UITableViewCell and Session object. Can't I provide anything I want when I am using AnyObject?

Comment: Is 'Session' a struct or a class?

Comment: You're just getting confused. You mean `closure` which is the object, not `configureCellClosure` which is its type.

Comment: And you're failing to store the closure as a stored property of the class, so it's not available in other methods at the moment now anyway.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type signatures don't match.  In the `init` declaration, the type of the closure is `(AnyObject, AnyObject) -> ()`, but when you actually call it, the type of the closure is `(UITableViewCell, Session) -> ()`. These aren't the same types.

In the `init` declaration, you're telling the compiler that you might call the closure with two parameters of any object type. The compiler believes you. It doesn't look at what you actually pass to the closure when you do eventually call it.

But later, when you actually pass in a closure, you're passing a closure that **cannot** take any two object references. It requires a reference to a `UITableViewCell` and a reference to a `Session`. If the program calls the closure with something that's not a `UITableViewCell` for `cell`, or something that's not a `Session` for `item`, then the program will probably crash. But you told the compiler (in the `init` declaration) that you might indeed call the closure with something other than a `UITableViewCell` or a `Session`. The compiler refuses to compile this program because it might crash.

Try this instead:

```
let callback = { (cell: AnyObject, item: AnyObject) -> () in
    guard let cell = cell as? UITableViewCell else {
        return
    }
    guard let item = item as? NSPredicate else {
        return
    }

    // do work here
}
```

### UPDATE

Your new error is because you're trying to call `configureCellClosure`, which is a type, instead of `closure`, which is the argument (to `init`) of that type. You need to rename `configureCellClosure` to `ConfigureCellClosure`, create a property in `SessionDataSource` of type `ConfigureCellClosure`, initialize the property in `init`, and call the property in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
    typealias ConfigureCellClosure = (cell: UITableViewCell) -> ()

    private let closure: ConfigureCellClosure

    init(closure: ConfigureCellClosure) {
        self.closure = closure
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        closure(cell: cell)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: I just think that encouraging the OP to continue to use AnyObject in code that he controls furthers rather than discourages bad design. AnyObject is largely for interacting with legacy Objective-C APIs.

Comment: @BaseZen Basically, the whole point is to use it in UITableViewController. This code can be reused by almost all the controllers and special needs can be fulfilled by the cellConfigureClosure.

Comment: @JohnDoe A little awkward with two comment threads running, but doesn't the final (edit -added) paragraph of my answer make the most sense?

Answer (score 1):

No, Swift cares too much about type safety. You're claiming to be passing in a [closure that takes as parameters a] UITableViewCell and a Session when you're really making no such guarantee. Functions are defined by their entire signature, which includes the function name, and the type and number of parameters. There's some larger design error or incorrect assumption you're making, such that you feel you need to accept a closure in your constructor that doesn't fit what you need to use it for.

Why not just force code that calls the constructor to pass in the right thing?

The closure can always, based on whatever mysterious logic, downcast `cell` from `UITableViewCell` to `MyFunkyTableViewCell` inside of it in order to configure properties specific to the latter subclass, and do other downcasts based on other conditional logic.

Comment: Basically this datasource can be used by many different entities so I will never know what is the correct type! However, I can cast it to the correct type once I get the cell and item back.

Comment: Your design is broken in a way that is hard to fathom with a tiny snippet. Your question probably needs to be about 4 times as long and spells out your design goals and some specific scenarios. I mean, it's called configure**Cell**Closure, and yet you don't want to define cell as what it is, a UITableViewCell. Anything that *inherits* from UITableViewCell is perfectly acceptable here.

Comment: Another possibility would be to define custom protocols and use them as types for the closure arguments instead of AnyObject.

Comment: I accept your suggestion for UITableViewCell but the second argument item can be anything! I guess anything which inherits from NSObject.

Comment: @JohnDoe How does your code use the second argument value without knowing anything about the API?

Comment: @jlehr When the closure returns the item I convert it to the type I want and then use it.

Comment: For some reason Swift does not like me using AnyObject. I can understand the type safety here but AnyObject was trying to provide flexibility.

Comment: When I was asking for a longer question, I meant along the lines of: what is the full *range* of types that this closure can generate for the 2nd param? How does that help you come up with a sensible constraint of a parent class type or protocol here? Unless you constrain your design it can spiral out of control. Granted such advice is a bit out of scope for this forum, but...anyway.

Comment: In any case, there's two separate issues here: good design, and getting the thing to compile. Use AnyObject all day and night, but the actual type being passed in (closure of (AnyObject, AnyObject)) has to match what's **wanted** by the receiver (closure of (UITableViewCell, Session)). If you had an AnyObject, would you understand that a function that expected a `String` argument would not accept it, such that your code wouldn't compile?

Comment: Thanks I actually got it to work! In the end where I receive the cell and item I caste the item to the entity I want and then simply use it.